# In what way social framework weaker than facebook sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Some says that we should use IOS SDK vs social framework.

What can we do with iOS SDK that we can't do with social framework?

Can we post on users' wall without having to ask user each time in social framework? In ios sdk?

Answer (score 2):

Social framework doesn't means FB. it is larger than only facebook, it includes facebook twitter,flicker and vimeo also. Facebook SDK is only for facebook and can perform various tasks related to facebook only.

Using social framework you will be able to post content on your facebook wall only but using facebook SDK you can use different dialogs to post on your friend's wall too.

other than this using Facebook SDK you can run FQL queries and graph operations too but it is not possible using social framework.

You may consider social framework as an app created on facebook with various permissions using which you can share content from your device such as photos and statuses but facebook SDK is a an SDK using which you may authorise other apps for permissions.

One last word
Facebook SDK + Social framework  = Awesome Mobile apps with superb UX

Comment: You mean we can use both at the same time? What about if I already login with social framework and then I want to post with facebook sdk or via versa?

Comment: yes we can do that. I have done the same in one of my application. User can login using social framework and then the access token which us created using social framework can be passed to facebook SDK. using that access token facebook SDK can perform various tasks. I am not 100% sure about vice-versa and i don't think that it will be needed too.

Comment: The SDK already wraps social framework log in functionality, so if the user is logged into Facebook via the social framework, the SDK can automatically get the session token from there.

Comment: @VaibhavGautam Can you please post some sample code how Facebook SDK can consume session created by Social Framework? I'm struggling to get my head around it.

Comment: I down voted because your statement "using Facebook SDK you can run FQL queries and graph operations too but it is not possible using social framework." Is simply not true. I am doing it with a SLRequest requestForServiceType:requestMethod:URL:parameters call.